# Custom directives not active in nested views when using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was working on an angular app (phonegap+ionic+angular), I had written a custom directive which registered an event listener for that element (which would activate iScroll for that element on load event). The directive was working fine when all the view was in index.html. I decided to refactor the code and intorduced nested views and routes using ui-router. Now the directive seems to be not functioning. I tried making a mock directive that would just console.log() and nothing happened. 
Am I missing something here?

Any kind of help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Most problems I have using nested directives come from losing the proper scope. Did you check that?

Comment: I have two controllers. One for the parent view and one for the nested view. Can you tell me (or point to some article) how to manage the scope between these two controllers? @MarioLevrero

Comment: Article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html  In addition, I use Batarang extension for Chrome to have a clear view of the scopes : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem and the solution to my problem. I'm posting here so that others facing similar problems could benefit from it.

Turns out, since my directive did not run because it was executed before the sub view was loaded. So I solved the problem by just adding a 
`scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded")` wrapper around my directive's codes and it started working.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point, I have 20 uiview's in a single page, before using ui-route I was using ng-include and ng-switch and all of my directives where working well, but with ui route the model which provide from service by using $http.get is not provide data inside directive until using scope.$watch('scope-attr-name').